# AjaxTOOLKIT rating sistem stars dont apear, asp.net webform

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hello, I've been trying to do a POSTS rating system for a few days, I see several tutorials talking about this, everyone uses ajaxtoolkit, I downloaded ajaxtoolkit, I installed, I did as I say, but the stars do not appear in the post, is a transparent space with clickable things, but without the stars!

CSS CODE:

```css
        .starempty {
            background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y6T8zFv.png");
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .starfilled {
            background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/rqzO2MZ.png");
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .starwaiting {
            background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/8uDtWlX.png");
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

ASPX CODE:

```
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" CurrentRating="1" MaxRating="5"
                                    StarCssClass="starempty" FilledStarCssClass="starfilled"
                                    WaitingStarCssClass="starwaiting" EmptyStarCssClass="starempty"
                                    runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

HOW IT APPEARS ON THE PAGE:

[PAGE DONT APEAR STARS!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjQaV.gif)

if they do not know how to solve it, is there any other framework something like this to do a rating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using local images and remember to put no-repeat:

```css
.starEmpty{
background-image: url(images/starempty.gif); 
width: 50px; 
height: 50px;
background-position: 0px 0px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I try this and still the same !

Comment: Did you put the images in a local folder? I copied your code as is to test and it worked for me with local images, the only difference being i used gifs instead of pngs